# How to plot a function with huge numbers?

Tags: plotting, big-numbers

I have a huge polynomial function `P` which is dependent on `x`, I tried plotting the function but I am getting nothing in the plot.

I am also interested in finding the roots of the equation.

```
P = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/YUfh8VBL"];
```

The function looks like this

```
Short[P]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[P, {x, 0, 100},PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: How was the polynomial generated? An expansion in terms of the power basis tends not to be numerically stable for root-finding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hack :

```
P := ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/YUfh8VBL"];
a = P /. x -> 0 (* order of magnitude of the expression *)
b = 
 Floor[Log[10, a]] 
f[u_] := (P /. x -> u)/10^b (* Scaling *)
Plot[f[u], {u, 0, 100}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", StringJoin["10^\.1d-", ToString@b, " y"]}]
```

[image]

You may want to experiment with `Ticks`to make the output nicer if needed.

Answer (score 9):

Since we are dealing with very large numbers, so one of the option is to use `ListLogPlot`

```
P[x_]:= Your large expression here 

ListLogPlot[Table[{x, P[x]}, {x, 0, 100, 10}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

For roots try with `NSolve` or `FindRoot`

```
NSolve[P[x] == 0, x]
```

Comment: But I am getting complex roots. I am doing frequency analysis of a mechanical system. I should suppose to real roots as my natural frequency. Is there any way to extract real roots, if exists?

Comment: `NSolve[P[x] == 0, x, Reals]` gives `{{x -> -39103.6}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 39103.6}}`

Answer (score 3):

Your polynomial is numerically a bit tricky because of (i) the huge coefficients and (ii) the high order. To calculate the roots, convert it to infinite precision first, and then compute the roots exactly with `Solve`:

```
P = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/YUfh8VBL"];
Q = SetPrecision[P, ∞];
R = Solve[Q == 0, x, Reals]
(*    24 Root objects    *)
```

convert to numerical values:

```
R // N
(*    {{x -> -39103.6}, {x -> -3535.84}, {x -> -3125.43}, {x -> -2202.52},
       {x -> -1624.8}, {x -> -1485.18}, {x -> -1239.14}, {x -> -905.892},
       {x -> -869.973}, {x -> -300.069}, {x -> -135.663}, {x -> -103.893},
       {x -> 103.893}, {x -> 135.663}, {x -> 300.069}, {x -> 869.973},
       {x -> 905.892}, {x -> 1239.14}, {x -> 1485.18}, {x -> 1624.8},
       {x -> 2202.52}, {x -> 3125.43}, {x -> 3535.84}, {x -> 39103.6}}    *)
```